# Extracting substring's from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

how to extract a specific part of a string from a large set of the paragraph.
Ex:*" Once upon a `time`, there was a `foolish King` who believed that he was the cleverest of all the people in his kingdom".*
how to extract strings which are enclosed within the backticks in javascript.
in this example, `time` and `foolish king` are enclosed within the backtick.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `String.match` to find out the matches, and then separate out the backticks from the matches:

```js
var string = "Once upon a `time`, there was a `foolish King` who believed that he was the cleverest of all the people in his kingdom";
var matches = string.match(/`([\w\s]+)`/g) || [];
matches = matches.map(m => m.slice(1, -1));

console.log(matches);
```